# Python: ball isn't defined

Tags: python, arrays

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python26/PYTHON-PROGRAMME/049 bam", line 9, in <module>
    ball[i][j]=sphere()
NameError: name 'ball' is not defined
```

when I run this code. But the ball is defined ( ball[i][j]=sphere() ). Isn`t it?

```
#2D-wave
#VPython

from visual import *

#ball array #ready
for i in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        ball[i][j]=sphere()

timer = 0
dt = 0.001
while(1):
    timer += dt

    for i in range(5):
        for y in range(5):
            #wave equation
            x = sqrt(i**2 + j**2) # x = distance to the source
            ball[i][j].pos.y = amplitude * sin (k * x + omega * timer)
    if timer > 5:
        break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `ball[i][j]`, you have to already have some object `ball` so that you can index (twice) into it. Try this segment instead:

```
ball = []    
for i in range(5):
    ball.append([])
    for y in range(5):
        ball[i].append(sphere())
```

Answer (score 3):

No, `ball` is not defined. You need to create a `list()` before you can start assigning to the list's indices. Similarly the nested lists need to be created before you assign to them. Try this:

```
ball = [None] * 5

for i in range(5):
    ball[i] = [None] * 5

    for j in range(5):
        ball[i][j]=sphere()
```

or this:

```
ball = [[sphere() for y in range(5)] for x in range(5)]
```

The latter syntax which uses two list comprehensions is more idiomatic--more Pythonic, if you will.

Comment: this will not work!! you will get `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`.

Comment: This code isn't valid. You can't assign to nonexistent list indices.

Comment: ball[i] = []
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't know that `ball` is a list. Before using it (in the first `for` loop), you'll have to initialize it as

```
ball = []
```

so Python knows to treat it as a list.

Answer (score 1):

no `ball` is not defined. this line: `ball[i][j]=sphere()` assigns value to an element of object `ball` points to. There is nothing `ball` points to therefore it's not possible to assign anything.

Answer (score 1):

In your program, `ball` is just a name that doesn't refer to anything. Using indexing like `a[i]` requires that `a` refer to an object that already supports indexing. Similarly, `a[i][j]` requires that `a[i]` refer to an object that supports indexing.

It sounds like you want it to refer to a list of lists, but *this is not a great solution*. You may be a lot happier performing your operations on numpy arrays, which abstract away all your looping and can really speed up computations.